# Laravel Blade include: How to pass variable from child to parent?

Tags: php, laravel

For example, in parent.blade.php:

```
<?php $a = 20; ?>
{{$a}}
@include("child")
{{$a}}
```

and in child.blade.php:

```
{{$a}}
<?php $a = 10; ?>
{{$a}}
```

the ouput:

```
20
20
10
20
```

It's clear that the variable was passed from the parent to the child, but changing it inside the child doesn't affect the parent variable. In addition, if the variable wasn't declared in the parent before including the child, it will of course through an error if used after the inclusion.

Comment: a blade include is its own independent view that is created from the view factory, the data is passed to it, it is rendered and the content is echoed, it is not a php include

Comment: @lagbox OK, I figured that out. How to solve it??

Comment: you would have to have an object, since they are just holding an object id, and make changes to that object, or you would have to assign data to the factory then pull it back out in the parent (or some other thing you could assign values to that you can access in both views)